# AngularJS: embedding ng-grid into bootstrap ng-modal causes $digest loop iterations reached

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

Has anyone successfully put a ng-grid inside a bootstrap ng-modal dialog?  I get the dreaded "10 iterations reached" $digest loop (invoked on $locationWatch).  It happens as soon as I open the modal.  After that, the modal and grid actually work just fine, but of course this loop is not acceptable.

thanks,

ed

Comment: A plunker or jsfiddle demonstrating the issue (with versions) would help us to answer. :)

Comment: You are right, I should've thought of that.  I'll create one tomorrow and follow up this comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-modal, have you tried using the [$modal service](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) from angular-ui?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said "ng-modal".   I am using the injected $modal service of Bootstrap-UI.  The html template has an ng-grid in it.  When the grid loads, the loop occurs.  No data is looked up initially, the grid is empty.